# using mathematica for plotting in C#

Tags: c#, plot, wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot some graphics for my course project via Mathematica. 
There is code from the project:

```
        try
        {
            toCompute = @"Show[RegionPlot[-2 <= x1 && x1 <= 2
                          && -2 <= x2 && x2 <= 2, {x1, -2, 
                         2}, {x2, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.7, 1, 1]], 
                        Table[ContourPlot[Sin[x1]*x2 == i, {x1, -2, 2},
                        {x2, -2, 2}], {i, -5, 5, 0.5}], PlotRange -> All]";

            Function.MathKernel.Compute(toCompute);
            if (Function.MathKernel.Graphics.Length > 0)
                Show(Function.MathKernel.Graphics[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Code works without any error, but result Image is empty (only background without graphic). If I type toCompure string into Mathematica - it plots the graphic.

Why so happens?

Comment: You could try in the sister site http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you post a minimal complete code, so we can compile it ?

Comment: why don't use zedgraph for that instead mathematica